# Rails Query with embedded jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My form has options to select a section based on previous selections. Once the section is selected I need to count and show how many Questions belong to the section.

I am trying to count the questions but cannot figure out the syntax. Here I am trying to update a @count variable every time a section is selected. Then assign the @count value to a hidden field which my table uses to add a row.

How do you do this query? The `$('#question_section')` is wrong syntax.

```
$('#question_section').change(function() {
            <% @count = Question.where(section: $('#question_section')).count %>
            $('input[name="question_count"]').val(<% @count %>);
   });
```

Comment: please check the idea and better way to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need more information. Basically the code of your view. I don't think you need to write any rails query inside your jquery. This shoud be pretty easy.

So far I assumed, from your form user will receive choices for section to questions. So the steps should be following.

You will bind the change event on your select httm input.

```
$("#question_section").on(function(){
    var value = $(this).value() // get whats the section value/text
})
```

Now get added an action on your controller where you will count the question with the query. So for this you will need to do to things. Registrar the action in route something like following:

```
resources :questions do  # I assume there is a questions resource 
    get :count, on: :collection
end
```

Now this will give you a url as route to that action. Now lets get back to javascript part again.

```
    $("#question_section").on(function(){
    var value = $(this).val() // get whats the section value/text
    $.ajax({
           url: '/questions/count.js', // you can skip the format here
           data: {section: value}
           success: function(data){
                  $('input[name="question_count"]').val(data)
           }
    })
    })
```

So now we are ready with the script. Now lets move to controller.

```
def count
    number_of_questions = Question.select("DISTINCT(section)").where(section: params[:section]).count
    render :js => number_of_questions
```

end

Well this is the steps you may follow. Direct query in the view layer is not acceptable. Responsibility centric design doesn't encourage that. I hope I can give some hints with my approach.

Comment: Let me if you need any help. @DDDD anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that everything between <% and %> is evaluated only once **on the server**. The rest of the code is evaluated afterwards as **JavaScript in the browser**. You'll have to expose this query in some controller:

```
Question.where(section: $('#question_section')).count
```

...and then ask the server for data every time the user changes the select:

```js
$('#question_section').change(function() {
  var url = "/path/to/your/service/" + $(this).val();
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    $('input[name="question_count"]').val(data.count);
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the path to your service? The controller method? How would you write the path to a controller method in JS?

Answer (score 0):

I am assumming that `section` attribute is a string or integer. Again assuming that the HTML element with the `id='question_select'` is a `<select>` tag, the jQuery line of code `$('#question_section')` will return a jQuery object (essentially a javascript object). 
And in the ActiveRecord Query Interface line of code `Question.where(section: $('#question_select'))` you have inserted the jQuery object when it will be expecting a `String` or `Fixnum` (integer in ruby) object depending on the datatype of `section`. That is the reason it is giving an error.

To fix this you can do the following ->

1. in javascript

   ```
   <script type="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#question').on('change',function(){
         var url = window.locatio.origin + '/questions/get_number_of_questions'
         var data = { section : $('#question_select').val() };
         $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: url,
           data: data,
           success: function(result){
             $('input[name="question_count"]').val(result[count]);
           }
         });
       });
     });
   ```
2. In your `routes.rb` file define a route for an action `get_number_of_questions` of type post under `questions`

   ```
   resources :questions do
     collection do
       post :get_number_of_questions
     end
   end
   ```
3. Finally in your `questions_controller.rb` file define the action

   ```
   class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
     ...

     def get_number_of_questions
       count = Question.where(section: params[:section]).count
       render :json { count: count }
     end

     ...
   end
   ```

Remember to keep your javascript and rails or ruby code as separate as possible. That is one of the best practices followed under RoR convention.
Hope this helps
Thank you.